# Ionic cordova build, does not compile! how to fix?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have an ionic version 1 project and ionic 4 CLI.

I try to build an android apk.

But the compiling fails and gives me the error: `Cannot find module 'C:\...\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js`

How can i fix it and compile an android version ?

```
λ ionic cordova build

? What platform would you like to build (android, ios): android
```

> ionic-v1 build

```
[15:17:57] Cannot run sass task: missing in gulpfile.js
```

> cordova build android

```
Unable to load PlatformApi from platform. Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\myuser\myapp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js'
(node:8824) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unhandled "error" event. (The platform "android" does not appear to be a valid cordova platform. It is missing API.js. android not supported.)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:186:19)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `ionic platform add android`and then `ionic build android`